# Stopping the infinite dialog loop

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

In short I want to know how to stop the multi-prompt example on the Microsoft sample git repo looping forever.

I've been looking over the V4 documentation and I am unable to find anything that's hinted at the solution here.

Microsoft have published a sample for making use of the multi-prompt dialog available here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt

If you clone and run the activity runs as follows;

you: send a message

bot: responds with opening dialog

you: respond to dialog

bot: advances to next step of dialog

....

continues to final step when it runs

```cs
return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The bot sends the final message in the waterfall steps and waits for another message from the user. Once again when the user sends any message the bot activates the dialog waterfall again.

Obviously because of this method in `DialogBot.cs`, every time the user sends a message the bot goes into the dialog.

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }
```

I want to stop that happening and only run the dialog once, the dialog should not activate again once the dialog ends the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at sample [45.state-management](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management) from the Botbuilder-Samples repo. It demonstrates how you can reference a set value in state to determine dialog flow. It would also be good for you to read over the "Save user and conversation data" doc, located [here](http://Save%20user%20and%20conversation%20data).

In short, you will need to do the following:

In the **Startup.cs** file, add the following. Be prepared to configure to meet your needs.

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
            services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

            // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled. 
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

            // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.) 
            services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

            // Create the User state. 
            services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

            // Create the Conversation state. 
            services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

            // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
            services.AddTransient<IBot, StateManagementBot>();
        }
    }
```

In your **"bot.cs"** file, do the following. Again, this is an example, so tailor to your needs. First, set the state objects (_conversationState, _userState). Once that is done, you can set and recall state values according to the dialog flow using those value to help drive the next action. In this example, state is being referenced in order to determine if a user's name should be asked for again, or not.

```cs
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class StateManagementBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private BotState _conversationState;
        private BotState _userState;

        public StateManagementBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
        {
            _conversationState = conversationState;
            _userState = userState;
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome to State Bot Sample. Type anything to get started.");
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the state properties from the turn context.

            var conversationStateAccessors =  _conversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
            var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Name))
            {
                // First time around this is set to false, so we will prompt user for name.
                if (conversationData.PromptedUserForName)
                {
                    // Set the name to what the user provided.
                    userProfile.Name = turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim();

                    // Acknowledge that we got their name.
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Thanks {userProfile.Name}. To see conversation data, type anything.");

                    // Reset the flag to allow the bot to go though the cycle again.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForName = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Prompt the user for their name.
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"What is your name?");

                    // Set the flag to true, so we don't prompt in the next turn.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForName = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Add message details to the conversation data.
                // Convert saved Timestamp to local DateTimeOffset, then to string for display.
                var messageTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset) turnContext.Activity.Timestamp;
                var localMessageTime = messageTimeOffset.ToLocalTime();
                conversationData.Timestamp = localMessageTime.ToString();
                conversationData.ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.ToString();

                // Display state data.
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{userProfile.Name} sent: {turnContext.Activity.Text}");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Message received at: {conversationData.Timestamp}");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Message received from: {conversationData.ChannelId}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you can track whether a user has already visited a particular dialog. If the value is true, then the dialog is skipped and the user is redirected. Hope of help!